# BitTorrent - Why doesn't the tracker send the IP Addresses of ALL peers to a new peer?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

Regarding BitTorrent, I read that the tracker randomly selects a **subset** (say, 20) of peers from the set of participating peers (say, 500), and sends the IP addresses of these 20 peers to a new peer. Out of curiosity, why doesn't the tracker send the IP addresses of ALL 500 peers to the new peer? Why does it only send 20?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't related to programming.

Comment: @HPierce, is there a better place to post questions about network protocols?

Answer (score 0):

Because having more peers isn't needed, 20 is easily enough. While having more peers makes the network more robust, it becomes much more costly. Also, sending the same number of peers every time makes the protocol simpler.

Comment: Costly in what sense?

Answer (score 0):

Only a finite amount of addresses fit into a non-fragmented UDP packet.